# How to use CellFactories for TreeItem<MyNode> instead of TreeItem<String>

Tags: javafx, treeview

I'm using following code to make some treeItems editable right in the treeview itself when someone double clicks on it. Recently I changed my TreeView so that it is populated with `TreeItem<MyNode>` instead of `TreeItem<String>`. The code for the editable cells isn't working now and I don't know what I should change about it:

TextFieldTreeCellImpl.java:

```
public final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {

    private TextField textField;

    String oldItem="";

    private Connection connection;
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=HOGENT1415_11";
    String user = "sa";
    String password = "root";
    Statement statement;

    public TextFieldTreeCellImpl(){
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
            }
        }

    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

This is the code which does the magic:

```
selectionTreeView.setEditable(true);
        selectionTreeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
            @Override
            public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
                TextFieldTreeCellImpl textField = null;
                textField = new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();
                return textField;
            }


        });
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to change the cell implementation so it is a `TreeCell<MyNode>`.  Try that (you will need to change the type of a lot of parameters from `String` to `MyNode`) and if you can't get it to work, update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks this worked, alongside something else (the commitedit part of the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What James_D said will normally work.

So change ALL the TreeCell to TreeCell.

Also pay attention to this line:

```
commitEdit(textField.getText());
```

This should become:

```
commitEdit(new MyNode(*parameters*));
```

I don't know what parameters that you have for MyNode but for example if you have a parameter of int type you also need to write an extra private method for this (like the getString method):

```
private String getItemInt() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().giveItemInt();
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to do the commitEdit part, my mistake. Everything is working now, thanks!